# Vue. Как увидеть, где ошибка в коде?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Непонятно, в каком месте в коде ошибка. Функционал вышел очень большим и на глаз определить не получается. Выдает лишь это:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at app.js:74768:67
    at Proxy.renderList (app.js:103287:18)
    at Proxy.render (app.js:74730:19)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (app.js:104206:24)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (app.js:104716:23)
    at Watcher.get (app.js:105128:27)
    at Watcher.run (app.js:105203:24)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (app.js:104961:15)
    at Array.<anonymous> (app.js:102632:14)
    at flushCallbacks (app.js:102558:16) 'LogRocket'
```

По всем строкам из ошибки прошёл - моего кода там нет.

Отключил почти всё, что мог, оставил только компонент, который вызывает функцию, которая вызывает эту ошибку. В `console.log` вывел каждую строку и там всё хорошо. Смысл ошибки понятен, но у меня нет данных, которые как-либо обрабатываются и получают `undefined`.

Оставил только этот код:

```
changeFilter(index,filterFilters) {
    this.filterNum = index
    this.activeFilters = filterFilters
    this.fetchedFilters = this.filters[index].fetchedFiltersItem
    this.staticFilters = this.filters[index].staticFiltersItem
    console.log(this.filterNum, this.activeFilters, this.fetchedFilters, this.staticFilters)
},
```

Из консоли выводятся все 4 пункта правильно, так, как задумано. То, что должно меняться после этого скрипта я отключил и всё равно ошибка появлялась

Vue v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда делаете запрос к указанной Вами функции вы передаете параметр `index`, который, как я подозреваю, является INT (целочисленная переменная), и, скорее всего, когда при первом вызове функции вы передаете `index = 0`, одна из 2-х строк, которая использует этот index, обращается к `undefined` как к массиву.

Строки о которых я говорю:

```
this.fetchedFilters = this.filters[index].fetchedFiltersItem
this.staticFilters = this.filters[index].staticFiltersItem
```

Убедитесь, что при вызове функции параметр `this.filters` не является `undefined`, ошибка как-раз и указывает на то, что она не может найти что-либо с индексом 0 в переменной, значение которой `undefined`

Comment: Спасибо. Ошибка была не так, но это натолкнуло на другую мысль в процессе чтения, ошибка была похожая, но в другом месте)